# Why The loop swaps values instead of writing them down one by one?

Tags: node.js

I encountered a problem that when executing the loop, it loads a value into JSONA and with each lap it is replaced with the new one, and the previous one disappears. Here is my code:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {

  const byUriArray = uriArray.map(nonceBsc => uris2[i].uri)
  const byIdArray = uriArray.map(nonceBsc =>  uris2[i].tokenId)

  const data = await axios.get(link + byUriArray[i]);

  console.log(data);

  fs.writeFileSync("newOgs.json", (JSON.stringify(data.data)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`writeFileSync` will set the contents of the file to the second parameter you pass. If anything was in the file previously, it'll be discarded.

If you wanted to save all results into the file, you'd have to either put the array of results into memory, then write the whole array:

```
const results = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
    const byUriArray = uriArray.map(nonceBsc => uris2[i].uri)
    const data = await axios.get(link + byUriArray[i]);
    results.push(data.data);
}
fs.writeFileSync("newOgs.json", JSON.stringify(results));
```

Or, since you're making lots of requests, perhaps also call `writeFileSync` on every iteration so that, if there's an error, you can resume instead of starting from the beginning again.

You also might want to add a delay inside the loop - 3000 network requests is a *lot*, and if you perform them one after the other, depending on the endpoint you're connecting to, you may get blocked due to abuse.